# Download multiple files inside foreach loop issue

Tags: php

I have the following code to download some log files through code

```
$files = array( '../tmp/logs/debug.log',
                '../tmp/logs/error.log');
    foreach($files as $file) {
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
        header("Content-Type: text/html");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        // read the file from disk
        readfile($file);
    }
```

But only download the first element of the array. In this case debug.log , if i swap the elements then only error.log. Any help please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only download one file per HTTP request. Effectively once the first file is sent the browser will assume that's the end of the processing and stops talking to the server.

If you want to ensure that the user downloads multiple files, one solution might be to zip them all up on-the-fly at the server-side, and then send the zip file to the user to download instead.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot download multiple files at once. The **HTTP protocol was designed to send one file per one request**.

Alternatively, you can zip all your log files and download it as a zip file.

You can use the [`ZipArchive`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class to create a ZIP file and stream it to the client. Something like:

```
    $files = array(
           '../tmp/logs/debug.log',
           '../tmp/logs/error.log'
    );
    $zipname = 'logs.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
      $zip->addFile($file);
    }
    $zip->close();
```

and to stream it:

```
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```

Answer (score 2):

Headers are setting up once in the same execution. If you put in a loop, the next headers will not send. You can make the loop in javascript and call with ajax, but the user will obtain multiple downloads at once, so it can crash browser and usability.